# Trying to see if values in a list exist in a mongoDB collection for a particular field

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a list of dictionaries called listCityStateZip.  One of the keys in listCityStateZip is called cityStateZip.  I want to see which of the cityStateZip values exist in a MongoDB collection called zipcodes (field: citystatezip).  If no match is found, then I want to flag that record in my list as "N".  If a match is found, I want to flag that record in my list as "Y".  I thought the code below would address my issues, but for some reason only the very first record in listCityStateZip (the list) ends up getting a flag.  Code shown below.  Two questions: 1) is there an easier way to write this code using python and 2) if not, why do I get a flag only in the very first record in my list?

```
for a in listCityStateZip:
    for b in db.zipcodes.find({'citystatezip': a['cityStateZip']},{'_id':1}):
        c.append(b)
        if len(c) == 0:
            a['flag'] = 'N'
        else:
            a['flag'] = 'Y'
        c=[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, much easier way

```
for a in listCityStateZip:
    if db.zipcodes.find({'citystatezip': a['cityStateZip']}).count() > 0:
        a['flag'] = 'Y'
    else:
        a['flag'] = 'N'
```

Comment: This is very helpful. Is there another MongoDB method that can be used to achieve the same effect rather than having to use a for loop on every value in the list listCityStateZip?